# How can I write the constraints and objective function when inventory is not given?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have this linear programming question.  Without knowing the level of inventory kept, how do I write the objective function or constraints for the questions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: You might want to add the `Homework` tag and show some effort using *Mathematica* code.  (This forum is not the 21st century version of Danny Dunn and the Homework Machine for the very few of you who might remember those books.)